# How will we add css property to the class in styled component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a doubt in styling the react components using styled-components. It is very easy in adding css property using styled-component to the button as below

```
const Button = styled.button`
      background: black;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      :disabled {
        opacity: 0.4;
      }
      :hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
      }
    `;
```

but when we look at the traditional way of styling the elements, i got stuck in it. Suppose we have button and i have added active class and css property to it as below

```
<button class='active'> click me</button>
.active{
   background: red;
   color: black;
}
```

How will we going to achieve the above way of styling an element in styled component. The problem what am facing currently is am dynamically adding class name to the button on click of it, i have to highlight the active button using 'active' class name by styled component.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the active prop inside the styled component. There you can add styling based on this prop like so;

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  :disabled {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  :hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
  }

  ${props => props.active && `
    /* only show this styling when active*/
    background: red;
    color: black;
  `}
`
```

Then you can "activate" active like so;

```
<Button active>click me</Button>
<Button active={true}>click me</Button>
```

And "de-activate" active like so;

```
<Button>click me</Button>
<Button active={false}>click me</Button>
```